# What is the purpose of having System.Action as a return type?

Tags: c#

The code I am working with looks like this:

Before:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CardsTabViewModel, Templates.Button>(this, "DeleteQuiz", async (s, btn) =>
{
   var canContinue = await DisplayAlert("Delete Quiz", "Do you want to delete the results for Quiz " + (int)btn.TapCommandParam, "OK", "Cancel");
   if (canContinue == false)
      return;
   App.DB.DeleteQuizHistory((int)btn.TapCommandParam);
   AddQuizDetails();
});
```

After:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CardsTabViewModel, Templates.Button>(this, "DeleteQuiz", NewMethod());

    }

private System.Action<CardsTabViewModel, Templates.Button> NewMethod()
{
   return async (s, btn) =>
   {
      var canContinue = await DisplayAlert("Delete Quiz", "Do you want to delete the results for Quiz " + (int)btn.TapCommandParam, "OK", "Cancel");
      if (canContinue == false)
         return;
      App.DB.DeleteQuizHistory((int)btn.TapCommandParam);
      AddQuizDetails();
    };
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the developer might have used System.Action as the return type. I've never seen System.Action used before and would like to try and understand what it does.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The `NewMethod`'s signature is problematic. It should be `private System.Func<CardsTabViewModel, Templates.Button, Task> NewMethod()`, so that the generated task can be awaited like this: `await NewMethod()(arg1, arg2);` Now the task is fired-and-forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Action` is just a delegate with a `void` return type, meaning you can call the action like you would a function upon return, or use it to create delegates of type void without explicitly defining one.

Here's an example of how you could use it for that:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void CallMe() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }

    public Action GetCallMe() { 
        return CallMe;
    }
}

...

private void Main(string[] args) {
    var classInstance = new SomeClass();
    Action a = classInstance.GetCallMe();
    a();
}
```

[System.Action Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.8)